# Unable to dockerize django

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to Docker, I have tried several video samples on youtube, yet I am unable to dockerize django app using anaconda

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
```

Here is docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
```

Here is requirements.txt

```
asgiref                   3.4.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
ca-certificates           2021.10.26           haa95532_2  
certifi                   2021.10.8        py39haa95532_2  
django                    3.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
krb5                      1.19.2               h5b6d351_0  
libpq                     12.9                 hb652d5d_1  
openssl                   1.1.1m               h2bbff1b_0  
pip                       21.3.1                   pypi_0    pypi
psycopg2                  2.8.6            py39hcd4344a_1  
python                    3.9.7                h6244533_1  
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
setuptools                58.0.4           py39haa95532_0  
sqlite                    3.37.0               h2bbff1b_0  
sqlparse                  0.4.1                      py_0  
typing_extensions         3.10.0.2           pyh06a4308_0  
tzdata                    2021e                hda174b7_0  
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1  
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2  
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
wincertstore              0.2              py39haa95532_2  
zlib                      1.2.11               h8cc25b3_4
```

After running "docker-compose build" I get this error message

```
=> ERROR [5/6] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                      3.1s 
------
 > [5/6] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt:
#10 2.240 ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'asgiref                   3.4.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0' (from line 4 of requirements.txt)
#10 2.933 WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.    
#10 2.933 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the normal format for a `requirements.txt` file; how did you create it?  Can you use it to set up a normal Python virtual environment, without Docker?

Comment: I created it with this command
```conda list > requirements.txt ```

Comment: You can use `pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt` if you see any format violation in `requirements` file.

Comment: or just `pip freeze >> requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First...

Create your requirements file from pip freeze >> requirements.txt

Ideally only those items you manually installed via pip install need to be in your requirements.txt file as all others will be installed as dependencies

Suggested changes to your Dockerfile:

```
...
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt  # copy [local source] [docker destination]

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip \  # upgrade pip
    && pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt  \  # install django requirements from destination
    && rm -rf /tmp/requirements.txt  # remove temp files
...
```

You were copying your requirements.txt file to the docker container under the /app folder.
Then when you tried running the pip install command, you weren't referring to that /app folder